# depicting specific element of a table (knowing its position) in different color

Tags: list-manipulation, data, grid-layouts

there is some 20 Time 20 tables, in each step we choose one element randomly. how can show this random selected element with different color?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Take a look at the answers to this question as well: [Identifying locations of entries in an array](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84467/27951).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We define a function `f` with the *style* of for the [`TextCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextCell.html)

```
Do[f[i, j] = Black, {i, 10}, {j, 10}]
```

We display the table as a [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html)entity

```
Dynamic@TableForm[
  Table[TextCell[Subsuperscript[X, i, j], f[i, j]], {i, 10}, {j, 10}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now every time you do a random selection, you can change the style of that specific cell, which will be updated in a `Dynamic` way. As an example, every second a random item with a random colour.

```
Do[
 Pause[1]; 
 f[RandomInteger[10], RandomInteger[10]] = 
  Sequence @@ {Bold, RandomChoice[{Red, Blue, Green}],   Background -> Yellow}
 , 100]
```

[image]

Comment: how you saved the dynamic table as a ".gif" ?

Answer (score 5):

For better presentation I've decreased size of matrices to 4.

```
n = 4;
MatrixForm[m = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {n, n}]]
```

[image]

```
With[{ij = {RandomInteger[{1, n}], RandomInteger[{1, n}]}},
  ReplacePart[m, ij -> Style[m[[Sequence @@ ij]], Red]]
  ] // MatrixForm
```

[image]